# Why Flutter CachedNetworkImage cannot put inside a Row or a Column?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, widget

**The question body is a little long but please read and understand my problem and help me out.**

**Thank you very much in advance**

I have a class called `ImageWidget` which extends `StatefulWidget`, it returns a `GestureDetector` which has a child `CachedNetworkImage`. My code is working, I'm able to call this `ImageWidget` class and able to display the image from anywhere if I return it as a single `Widget`.

**Like this** *(These codes are all working)*

```
return ImageWidget(
      imageUrl: imageUrl,
    );
```

```
return Container(
        child: ImageWidget(
      imageUrl: imageUrl,
    ));
```

```
return Center(
        child: ImageWidget(
      imageUrl: imageUrl,
    ));
```

My goal here is to display a list/multiple of this `ImageWidget` by using a `Row` or `Column` or `ListView`. I can put this `ImageWidget` class to anywhere (such as `Center`, `Container`) except `Row` or `Column` or `ListView` which takes multiple children.

**Like this** *(These code doesn't work; not able to display the image; also no error)*

```
return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        ImageWidget(
          imageUrl: imageUrl,
        ),
        ImageWidget(
          imageUrl: imageUrl,
        ),
        ImageWidget(
          imageUrl: imageUrl,
        )
      ],
    );
```

Whenever I put my `ImageWidget` to any of these `Widgets` (`Row` or `Column` or `ListView`) the image doesn't show up. I think the problem is with the `imageBuilder` because when I remove it or set it to `null` it works but I can't do it, I need to maintain the shape of the image.

**ImageWidget.dart class**

```
    import 'package:analog_components/Utilities/MessageUnilities.dart';
    import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class ImageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
      final String imageUrl;
      final BoxShape shape;
      final BoxFit fit;

      ImageWidget(
          {this.imageUrl, this.shape: BoxShape.rectangle, this.fit: BoxFit.contain})
          : assert(imageUrl != null),
        assert(shape != null),
        assert(fit != null);

      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        return _ImageWidget();
      }
    }

    class _ImageWidget extends State<ImageWidget> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        print('image widget');
        return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
              MessageUtilities.showShortToast('tap');
        },
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: widget.imageUrl,
          placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
          imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: widget.shape,
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: imageProvider,
                fit: widget.fit,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
            )
        );
      }
    }
```

If I put the `ImageWidget` to a `CircularAvatar` than it works, I can put it in a `Row` or `Column`.

```
return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        CircleAvatar(
          radius: 50,
          child: ImageWidget(
            imageUrl: imageUrl,
          ),
        ),
        CircleAvatar(
          radius: 50,
          child: ImageWidget(
            imageUrl: imageUrl,
          ),
        ),
        CircleAvatar(
          radius: 50,
          child: ImageWidget(
            imageUrl: imageUrl,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

[image]

also, I can't do it because the image is broken and I don't want the circular image. I need to maintain a rectangular `BoxFit.contain` shape.

Comment: If you are wrapping your widgets in a Row or Column either the widget should have a finite height or width depending on which layout or either the Row or Column should have a finite width or height.

Comment: Instead of defining the height: 200, how can I use something like wrap_content to maintain the exact width and height of the Image (CachedNetworkImage).

Comment: I did width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width but without the height, the image doesn't display. I don't know I much I should define for the height, I want the exact height of the image.

Comment: You want the images in a row or column

Comment: I'm gonna use it both Row and Column. If I set the height and width I can display in both row and column but It doesn't show the exact size of the image. What I want is something like  `height->wrap_content` and `width->wrap_content` in the `Container`

Comment: You mean like a grid?

Comment: I'm going to design a Widget like an Instagram Post where the image height is fixed to the heigh of the image and width is large as it's parent (in this case I'm going to use Column).

Comment: Got it. So its like a Column and width should be maxed and height is dynamic right

Answer (score 2):

Your ImageWidget can work with Row and Column 
Wrap CachedNetworkImage with Container and set height/width 
For placeholder, you can use Container(), so CircularProgressIndicator will not show

```
child: Container(
          height: 200,
          child: CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: widget.imageUrl,
            placeholder: (context, url) => Container(),
            imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: widget.shape,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: imageProvider,
                  fit: widget.fit,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
          ),
        )
```

and call like this

```
ImageWidget(
              imageUrl: 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
```

full code

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
             Expanded(
               flex: 1,
               child: ImageWidget(
                  imageUrl: 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
             ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: ImageWidget(
                imageUrl: 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

class ImageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String imageUrl;
  final BoxShape shape;
  final BoxFit fit;

  ImageWidget(
      {this.imageUrl, this.shape: BoxShape.rectangle, this.fit: BoxFit.contain})
      : assert(imageUrl != null),
        assert(shape != null),
        assert(fit != null);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ImageWidget();
  }
}

class _ImageWidget extends State<ImageWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('image widget');
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          //MessageUtilities.showShortToast('tap');
          print("tap");
        },
        child: Container(
            child: CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl: widget.imageUrl,
              placeholder: (context, url) => Container(height: 0, width: 0,),
              imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: widget.shape,
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: imageProvider,
                    fit: widget.fit,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
            ),
        ));
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of defining the `height: 200`, how can I use something like `wrap_content` to maintain the exact width and height of the Image (CachedNetworkImage).

Comment: I did `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` but without the height, the image doesn't display. I don't know I much I should define for the height, I want the exact height of the image.

Comment: I have updated my full code. In Container, you call just use Container, no height need. and outside when you use ImageWidget, you can use Expaned flex to control relative height size.

Comment: flutter need image height to render either fixed or relative to screen size. could depend on your outer layout

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is give the width of the device which you can get from `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`

Then set these two properties of CachedNetworkImage

```
  CachedNetworkImage(
              width: width,
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
```